# Struggling with keyboard inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this code to see a keyboard input using msvcrt which looks like this:

```
import msvcrt 

def kbfunc(): 
    x = msvcrt.kbhit()
    if x: 
        ret = ord(msvcrt.getch()) 
    else: 
        ret = 0 
    print(ret)
while True:
    kbfunc()
```

But when I run this code, all that is printed is 0s over and over. How do I amend this?
Thank you

Comment: `kbhit` and `getch` only work for keyboard input in a console window. They don't work in IDLE, or any other GUI environment that doesn't use a console. You can call WinAPI `AllocConsole` or `AttachConsole`, and then type into the attached console window. Once attached you can open "CONIN$" to read from the console and "CONOUT$" to write to it.

Comment: @eryksun Could you possibly post a code which would show this because I am struggling to understand without an example

Comment: Is this just for debugging in IDLE? If so, you may find it easier to run it from a command prompt via `py -3 -m idlelib`. Then for testing you can type into that console window. Your script should be a .py file that runs via python.exe. This will automatically inherit or allocate a console.

Comment: @eryksun Essentially, I am creating a game using tkinter and need the player to activate the functions by pressing arrow keys to move etc. but I need a way to log the inputs so I can check if it's the arrow I want. So I looked this up to see basically how to get a keyboard input but don't know how it works.

Comment: Ok, you need to handle key events in tkinter. For Python 2 examples, see [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm). In Python 3 the names and package layout are different, but it shouldn't be difficult to get the examples working.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you very much this is very helpful